# BDD in PHP, Testing search in Wikipedia with Behat and Mink (Selenium2 Driver)

Tags: php, bdd

I am trying to learn BDD in PHP with [Behat](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/) and [Mink](http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/) and I am using [Selenium2 driver](http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/drivers/selenium2.html) for the same.

The scenario is given on [this page](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/cookbook/behat_and_mink.html) and is as follows:

> ```
> Feature: Search
>     In order to see a word definition
>     As a website user
>     I need to be able to search for a word
>
>     Scenario: Searching for a page that does exist
>         Given I am on "/wiki/Main_Page"
>         When I fill in "search" with "Behavior Driven Development"
>         And I press "searchButton"
>         Then I should see "Behavior-driven development"
>
>     Scenario: Searching for a page that does NOT exist
>         Given I am on "/wiki/Main_Page"
>         When I fill in "search" with "Glory Driven Development"
>         And I press "searchButton"
>         Then I should see "Search results"
> ```

The file behat.yml is as follows:

```php
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url: http://en.wikipedia.org/
            goutte: ~
            selenium2: ~
```

I have written the below code for FeatureContext.php that I am sure needs improvements. Can anyone suggest me the points for the same?

```php
<?php

use Behat\Behat\Tester\Exception\PendingException;
use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Behat\Context\SnippetAcceptingContext;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;

/**
* Defines application features from the specific context.
*/
class FeatureContext implements Context, SnippetAcceptingContext
{
    /**
    * Initializes context.
    *
    * Every scenario gets its own context instance.
    * You can also pass arbitrary arguments to the
    * context constructor through behat.yml.
    */
    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->driver = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver('firefox');
        $this->session = new \Behat\Mink\Session($this->driver);        
        $this->session->start();
    }


    /**
    * @Given I am on :url
    */
    public function iAmOn($url)
    {
        $this->session->visit('http://en.wikipedia.org'.$url);
    }

    /**
    * @When I fill in :field with :text
    */
    public function iFillInWith($field, $text)
    {
        $this
            ->session
            ->getPage()
            ->find('css', '[type=' . $field . ']')
            ->setValue($text);
    }

    /**
    * @When I press :button
    */
    public function iPress($button)
    {
        $this
            ->session
            ->getPage()
            ->find('css', '[id=' . $button . ']')
            ->press();
    }

    /**
    * @Then I should see :text
    */
    public function iShouldSee($text)
    {
        $title = $this
            ->session
            ->getPage()
            ->find('css', 'h1')
            ->getText();

        if ($title !== $text) {
            new Exception('Invalid page');
        }
    }

    /**
    * @AfterScenario
    */
    public function tearDown()
    {
        $this->session->stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one major point that we can do here. In the `FeatureContext.php`, if class `FeatureContext extends MinkContext`, then you do not need to write any of the function definitions at all!

Applying what I just said, will result to have `FeatureContext.php` to be as:

```
<?php

use Behat\Behat\Tester\Exception\PendingException;
use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Behat\Context\SnippetAcceptingContext;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;
use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext; //This line is add

class FeatureContext extends MinkContext // This line is changed
    implements Context, SnippetAcceptingContext
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }
}
```

**Note:** To make the point more clear, I have removed the comments that are generated by behat.